# Change in angle due to rotation in another plane

Tags: geometry

I hope someone can help me figure this out.

Step 1: We are looking at the ZX plane (front view). I have two lines, which have been rotated 15 degrees around the Y axis. At this step both lines are identical (except for the colour).
[image: Step 1]

Step 2: We are now looking at the XY plane (top view). I take the yellow line and rotate it 60 degrees around the Z Axis.
[image: Step 2]

Step 3: We are back at our starting view (ZX plane - front). The angle of the yellow line and the X-Axis is 28.18679 degrees. How can this angle be calculated?

** EDIT **
I used a CAD program to draw this, and I also used the CAD program to measure the angle. I need to calculate the angle programatically though.

[image: Step 3]

Thanks a million!

Comment: It seems that you already calculated it? :-)

Comment: @joriki No, I used a CAD program to draw this. I used the CAD program to measure the angle. I need to calculate the angle programatically. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The direction vector of the yellow line is

$$
\pmatrix{\cos\theta\cos\phi\\\cos\theta\sin\phi\\\sin\theta}
$$

with $\theta=15^\circ$ and $\phi=60^\circ$. Thus its angle with the $x$ axis is

$$
\arccos\left(\cos\theta\cos\phi\right)=\arccos\left(\cos15^\circ\cos60^\circ\right)\approx61.1^\circ\;.
$$

Since this is far from your measurement of $\approx28.2^\circ$, it seems that what you're interested in may in fact not be the angle of the yellow line with the $x$ axis. The image suggests that the angle you're measuring is the angle between the $x$ axis and the projection of the yellow line onto the $x$-$z$ plane. This is indeed

$$
\arctan\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta\cos\phi}=\arctan\frac{\sin15^\circ}{\cos15^\circ\cos60^\circ}\approx28.18679^\circ\;.
$$

Comment: thank you! This is indeed what I was needing. The projection of the yellow line onto the ZX plane.

How did you come up with this formula? Does it have any name? I would like to learn how to be able to determine such a formula. Can you please give me some broad topics I should learn in oder to be able to do this?

Thanks!!!!

Comment: @santiagoIT: Broadly speaking, you should look into [trigonometric functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions). In the present case, the tangent of the angle that the projection of the line onto the $x$-$z$ plane forms with the $x$ axis is the ratio of the $z$ component of its direction vector, $\sin\theta$, to the $x$ component of its direction vector, $\cos\theta\cos\phi$. Then take the arctangent on both sides to arrive at the above formula. You might also want to look into [spherical coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system).

Comment: Would you be able to suggest a general approach for finding new angles after a rotation in $n$-dimensions? Say we start out with a spherical cone defined by some angles $[\theta_1, \theta_2, ..., \theta_{n-1}]$ and then we rotate the sphere with matrix $\mathbf{R}$ - what would be the new angles of the spherical cone? I've tried to find them by taking projections of rotated vectors onto various planes and then taking dot products between these projections and original vectors but it gets quite confusing and I feel there must be a simper way of getting these from the rotation matrix. Thank you

Comment: PS.  The cone is defined by two sets of angles, not one as I wrote in the previous comment: $\theta_1^{min}, \theta_1^{max}$, etc.  Thank you.